# Projecting Revenue in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So we are building a spreadsheet to project sales and revenue.   In our business, we sign a deal, we get implementation revenue the month after we sign the deal, then we get the recurring revenue for several years but it doesnt start until implementation is completed which can be 3-12 months.

So I am trying to build a projection that will show as an example, a sale made in January, that the implementation revenue is realized in February, and then the recurring revenue is X dollars per month starting in June for 36 months.

Is there a reasonable way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Can you clarify what aspect is causing you problems?  Is the issue that you want to automate placement of the values and can't figure out how to calculate what columns the formulas/values should go in?

Comment: I have defined sales revenue target amounts, projected sales and so for instance, I have small account defined with one time revenue and recurring revenue, and I also have a medium account defined for both revenue types.   I then want to project a sale of each in say September.  The one time revenue (I will use small amounts for ease) 100 for the small, 200 bucks for medium account falls in October, and then recurring revenue starts in December, a different amount for each.   I have a table of four target accounts with one time, recurring revenue defined, and I want to auto fill in revenue.

Comment: I have the start of the sheet but I dont think I can load it to see can I?

Comment: If you can take screen shots, post links to them at any publicly-accessible sharing service, like imgur.com, and someone will embed them for you.  It will be easier to follow your explanation if someone can look at an example.